# Why do I get a 'cannot find symbol class' error on my Android import statement (ActionBarActivity) after updating appcompat to 27.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-actionbaractivity, cannot-find-symbol

Why do I get a 'cannot find symbol class' error on my Android import statement (ActionBarActivity) after updating appcompat to 27.1?  I am getting the following error, on the following import statement.  Notice the import statement is now greyed out:

```
Error:(16, 30) error: cannot find symbol class ActionBarActivity
```

[image]

I only updated my build.gradle file (the lines I changed are indicated with double asterisks) so that it now looks like:

```
    **compileSdkVersion 27**
    **buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'**
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        **targetSdkVersion 27**
        versionCode 47
        versionName "1.3.35"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

... 
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    compile files('libs/okhttp-3.6.0.jar')
    // major number should always match compileSdkVersion above
    compile files('libs/square-otto-1.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/core-3.3.0.jar')
}
```

Android Studio is fully updated.  I'm using 3.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ActionBarActivity` was removed around the time of `26.0.0`. [Switch to `AppCompatActivity`](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) to continue using `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: Indeed that is the solution.  They will allow me to accept your answer as correct in 5 min.  Thank you for your service to this community.  You've helped me several times.  Maintaining a certain Android app is only one of my duties so it is impossible for me to keep up with everything Android as if it were my full-time job.